# SwiftUI Update @State in closure

Tags: swift, objective-c, swiftui, closures

Below is SwiftUI code in question.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var connection = false

    let disconnectListener: DisconnectListener = {
        class Anonymous: NSObject, DisconnectListener {
            func onDisconnect() {
                // connection variable is invisible and cannot update this ... 
                connection = false
            }
        }
        return Anonymous()
    }()

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $connection) {
            Text("Connection").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
        }.onChange(of: connection) { _ in
            if connection {
                // Listener provided by @protocol in Objective-C.
                controller.add(disconnectListener)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to do it like `anonymous class` and add it to `controller`.

Is there way to update `@State` `connection` variable from `onDisconnect()` method ?

Answer (score 1):

You should move your `Anonymous` class outside of your `View` and store `connection` on that.

```
class Anonymous: NSObject, DisconnectListener, ObservableObject {
  @Published var connection: Bool

  init(connection: Bool) {
    self.connection = connection
  }

  func onDisconnect() {
    // connection variable is invisible and cannot update this ...
    connection = false
  }
}

struct ConnectionView : View {
  @ObservedObject var disconnectListener: Anonymous

  var body: some View {
    Toggle(isOn: $disconnectListener.connection) {
      Text("Connection").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
    }.onChange(of: disconnectListener.connection) { connection in
      if connection {
        // Listener provided by @protocol in Objective-C.
        controller.add(disconnectListener)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You now need to inject `Anonymous` into `ConnectionView`

```
let connectionView = ConnectionView(disconnectListener: Anonymous(connection: false))
```